# Primeng Editor adding undo and redo button

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng

How Can I add the undo & redo button in Primeng editor i.e quill editor.
I have checked Primeng documentation and also some example but can not find any solution of it

Primeng version: 9.1.0,
Quill: 1.3.7

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="consultationNotes"
                name="ConsultationNotes{{ searchVideoConsultation.ObjectID }}" fieldLabel="" toolbar="false"
                [style]="{'height' : 'auto'}"></p-editor>
```

Comment: Could you please add your project and primeng version. Also if you will add more detail about your code or problem you will quickly your fix problem

Comment: "primeng": "^9.1.0",
        "quill": "^1.3.7"

<p-editor [(ngModel)]="consultationNotes"
                name="ConsultationNotes{{ searchVideoConsultation.ObjectID }}" fieldLabel="" toolbar="false"
                [style]="{'height' : 'auto'}"></p-editor>

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer,

First you should import undo and redo icons in your project .ts file as below,

```
    var icons = Quill.import("ui/icons");
    icons["undo"] = `<svg viewbox="0 0 18 18">
    <polygon class="ql-fill ql-stroke" points="6 10 4 12 2 10 6 10"></polygon>
    <path class="ql-stroke" d="M8.09,13.91A4.6,4.6,0,0,0,9,14,5,5,0,1,0,4,9"></path>
  </svg>`;
    icons["redo"] = `<svg viewbox="0 0 18 18">
    <polygon class="ql-fill ql-stroke" points="12 10 14 12 16 10 12 10"></polygon>
    <path class="ql-stroke" d="M9.91,13.91A4.6,4.6,0,0,1,9,14a5,5,0,1,1,5-5"></path>
  </svg>`;
```

then you should add undo and redo functions like this,

```
  undo() {
    this.editorComponent.quill.history.undo();
  }
  redo() {
    this.editorComponent.quill.history.redo();
  }
```

last if you can add .html file below code,

```
<p-header>
 <span class="ql-history">
     <button aria-label="Undo" (click)="undo()"  class="ql-undo"></button>
     <button aria-label="Redo" (click)="redo()" class="ql-redo"></button>
   </span>
</p-header>
```

[Demo is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quill-55477705-zztu5b?file=src/app/app.component.html)